# Deployed website in a server cannot be accessible

Tags: .net, windows, iis, server

We have deployed the website in the iis at a server (say 192.168.1.96).

If We access the default site using http://192.168.1.96, then we can access the default site.

If we access the deployed site using http://192.168.1.96:12222, then we can not access the deployed website.

If we login to the server and access like http://localhost:12222 or http://192.168.1.96:12222, we can do. But outside the network, we cannot do.

What we can do for this to be accessible outside the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first thing i suggest is that you guys havent opened the port 12222 for outside connections.

On Servers especially Windows Servers, are all non standart port blocked by default.

Navigate to your firewall and create a new income rule to open that port!

Greetings,
Lars